# I can't figure out why my simple attempt at adding an event handler isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a click event to a button on my web page. Its a simple button created with a  tag and I set the id attribute to "button1". In the javascript code, I used getElementById to store the button in the variable btn and used the onClick method to add the click event. The function is basic and only displays an alert box.Simple, right?

But for some reason, clicking the button doesn't do anything. I don't see where I went wrong. I double checked my spelling everywhere, so it isn't a typo. Did I miss a step somewhere?

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Add Event Handler</title>
    <head>
    <body>
      <h1>Add Event Handler</h1>

      <button id="button1">Click Me</button>

      <script>
        function test(){
          alert("The event handler was set.");
        }

        var btn = document.getElementById("button1");
        btn.onClick = test;
     </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, and noted the addEventListener method.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

```
    btn.onclick = test;
```

not

```
    btn.onClick = test;
```

```html
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Add Event Handler</title>
    <head>
    <body>
      <h1>Add Event Handler</h1>

      <button id="button1">Click Me</button>

      <script>
        function test(){
          alert("The event handler was set.");
        }

        var btn = document.getElementById("button1");
        btn.onclick = test;
     </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: This is vanilla javascript not React . :)

Comment: Relevant documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
btn.addEventListener('click', test, false)
```